# why conditional or doesn't evaluates to boolean value when assigned to a variable

Tags: javascript, conditional-operator

inside conditional statement any logical operation will evaluate to a boolean value which determines whether or not the conditional block will be executed or not. Like the following statement will determine the IF statement will execute or not

```
if(null || 1){} // evaluates to boolean value
```

but the same conditional statement will evaluates to Number value when assigned to a variable.Consider this:

```
var x = null || 1 // x will become 1
```

my another question is does the order of null and 1 matters here?

what determines when a conditional operation will become Boolean or Number ?

Comment: the first code is not a boolean result - it's "truthy"

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy

Comment: The `||` expression is evaluated *first* resulting in `1` in both cases, then *that* value is evaluated as the `if` condition. Asking about the order of the operands is a bit pointless when both are hardcoded literals and you know the result in advance, but the order definitely matters in a general sense because JS uses short-circuit evaluation. So `if (func1() || func2())` will only call the second function if the first's result is falsy.

Comment: @nnnnnn but if(null || 1) and if(1||null) both evaluates to true.In what context you said that order matters?

Comment: but var x = null || ' ' returns x = " " // empty string. In this case both is false . why x is empty string instead of null ?

Comment: I've deleted my previous comment because it only covered whether the result would be truthy or falsy. To answer your last comment, what the `||` operator does is return the first operand if it is truthy, otherwise return the second operand. So if both operands are falsy the second one will be returned as in your `null || ""` example. Whereas what the `&&` operator does is return the first operand if it is falsy, otherwise return the second operand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They both result in the same thing. The difference, however, is that the `if` statement parses the value as a boolean: the `1` returned is parsed as a boolean.

```
> (null || 1)
1
> Boolean(1)
true
```

The `if(null || 1){}` simply evaluates to `if(1){}` which in turn evaluates to `if(true){}` since `1` is truthy.

**Thus, there is no deterministic difference, the `if` statement simply parses the parameter as a boolean while the variable definition merely returns the number itself.**

From [**mozzila.org**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy):

> In JavaScript, a truthy value is a value that is considered true when evaluated in a Boolean context. All values are truthy unless they are defined as falsy (i.e., except for `false` , `0` , `""` , `null` , `undefined` , and `NaN` ). JavaScript uses type coercion in Boolean contexts

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript, `1` is "truthy", which is why the `if` statement is entered. Basically, `(null || 1)` always evaluates to `1`, but if forced, we say that it's `true` rather than `false`.

Comment: There's nothing about being forced—`1` is intrinsically `true`, as all non-zero numbers are.

Comment: 1 is not intrinsically true, it depends on the language. See ruby, where only `true` is true - everything else (including 1), is false.

Comment: in javascript 1 is definitely true in an intrinsic way; intrinsic meaning essential or natural, not meaning spanning all languages.

Comment: For example, try casting `true` to a `Number` (`Number(true)`). You get `1`.